# Scatter objects on a fluid mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation, effects

I'm trying to simulate the effect in this video: https://www.instagram.com/p/CtHEIhRvA36/

[image]

I started creating a fluid simulation and then I wanted to scatter some grass on the domain mesh;
The problem is the consistency of the scatter because the mesh continuously evolves and the distribution of the grass changes every frame. Is there a method, maybe in geometry nodes, to obtain a consistent result?

Comment: Literally having the same problem, trying to recreate the same animation - from the instagram post 
Unfortunately still no solution found, so i can't help :/

Comment: Now I'm trying to avoid scattering and only render the fluid simulation points as objects and not as spheres. The consistency is now ok, but the result sucks 